# Archimedean property application with logarithms

Tags: proof-verification

I am attempting this proof but do not know what to do about assuming the sign of $a$. Is this proof correct?I don't think it is because the result is supposed to hold for all $a$

The problem is prove if $a \in \mathbb{R}$,$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a<10^n$.

My attempt assume $a>0$ then $log(a) \in \mathbb{R}$

Then by the Archimedean property there exists a natural number such that

$n>log(a) \implies 10^n>a$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @DonThousand is it okay here to assume $a$ is positive, what about when it is negative or zero?

Comment: Don't need to assume. $n=1$ works when $a\leq0$.

Comment: sounds good thanks